# What's the correct syntax in VBA for an "OR"?

Tags: vba, ms-word

What's the correct syntax to do this?

```
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    .Text = "STRING1" Or "STRING TWO"
```

Comment: (Can't follow the code at the link.)  Mine is a very simple syntax Q.  My code works if I'm just looking for STRING1.  But if I add a STRING TWO (in a new OR clause, as in the code sample) as well it fails.  How do I fix the syntax?  Thanks.

Comment: try to write it like that: `.Text = "STRING1" Or  .Text = "STRING TWO`

Comment: @manu -- tried that previously and syntax didn't work (in Word VBA).

Comment: Either you do two searches or you use any of the many solutions with Worksheet functions and array formulas.

Comment: pipe is also not working.

Comment: `ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Text`  is object's `ActiveDocument.Range.Find` property could not assigned by two value that `.Text="STRING1" Or .Text="STRING TWO"`. `"STRING1" Or "STRING TWO"` - operator is Boolean return true or false. to assign a `.text` property you need a string result! Why you not use two operator `ActiveDocument.Range.Find` subsequently first with `.Text="STRING1"` with second `.Tex="STRING TWO"`

Comment: Ivan.s is correct: Word's Find functionality does not support "OR" and you need to execute Find separately for each search term. HOWEVER if the second search term is a slight variation on the first it's sometimes possible to get an "or effect" using Wildcards. Since you don't show us the two strings, it's impossible to say whether this might be the case in this instance...